# Working with dates in SQL query using MDB-Tools

Tags: sql, ms-access, mdbtools

I have been working on a project where I have to fetch data from MS-Access database. I am using mdb-sql tool for running sql queries into that database. But the problem occurs when I try to put where clause on a datetime column. It always throws a syntax error.

Please help me how can I use dates in where column.
I have tried using these queries -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE checkintime > '04/22/13 12:15:39'

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE checkintime > #04/22/13 12:15:39#
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the date in format like this: `'20130422 12:15:39'` ?

Comment: No. I didnt try. Actually date format in the column is same as I mentioned in question , so i tried with same format

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

mdb-sql displays human-readable dates in results, but requires timestamp values in queries -- calculated as the number of seconds sine 1/1/1970 (the beginning of the UNIX epoch).

So the correct query to extract all records with a date greater than 04/22/13 12:15:39  would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE checkintime > 1366650939
```

An easy way to calculate this from the command line is:

```
 date --date='04/22/13 12:15:39' +"%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
MS Access: Format Function (with Dates):

```
where Format([checkintime ],"yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")>='2013-04-22 12:15:39'
```